# Nearest geopoint that is on road

Tags: osmdroid

I get a geopoint from my database as a response to query.
I need to know the best way to find the nearest point on a road for the recieved geopoint.

Tried to create a table with all geopoints on road, manually, but it is taking too much effort.

Is it possible to get all the points on roads in a city using some queries?

Are there services to get the nearest point on road/nearest road, points on a road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Are there services to get the nearest point on road/nearest road, points on a road?"

Yes: routing services. They are particularly good to provide, from any point on the map, the closest point on the closest road.

You can experiment with the [OSRM web interface](http://map.project-osrm.org/) for instance.

When using osmdroid, you can very easily access to routing services by using [OSMBonusPack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack).

Comment: http://open.mapquestapi.com/guidance/ referred in osmbonuspack tutorial gives a wide variety of options with RoadManager.Thanks a ton for giving the reference.But I'm now confused how to solve my problem (getting nearest geopoint on road , within 200m radius of my reference geopoint RefGP). Should I calculate all possible points(PeriGPs) on circle of radius 200m and send them (RefGP and a PeriGP) to get a road between them?

Comment: Well, in fact, there is something even simpler: OSRM "nearest point" API, described here => https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Server-api, "Nearest point on a street".

Comment: I might seem stupid with this question:I need points for one time usage. should I set up osrm server myself? or Can I use url like http://map.project-osrm.org/?nearest?loc=52.4224,13.333086 to get nearest points on road?

Comment: Not stupid at all! Check OSRM API policy (https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Api-usage-policy).